# Can Workflow Foundation be used in this scenario?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I want to write a asp.net based game which has rules(of course) I want this: When the user fills the form and clicks the button it will check the inputs according to rules and save the outputs to the db or show to user.

-Can I write the rules using WF?

-Can I exchange data between asp.net form-wf-db?

-Can somebody edit the rule file during runtime of web application?(Or replace the .xaml file completely?)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes.  But it is very difficult and beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be possible but I don't think WF4 would be an ideal fit. The one thing you can't do is modify an workflow declaration while the workflow is running.